# react/redux:Get the latest props value from state after updating props with dispatch right away

Tags: reactjs, redux

I encounter synchronous props that is mapped from state after updating props with dispatch issue .

In JSX, when I change select dropdown, then trigger `handleChange` method. In `handleChange`, it execute `selectLayoutAction` action, dispatch the action, update `selectLayout` property of state, after that I need to use the updated `selectLayout` property in next line for updating component state, but I can't get the new `selectLayout` value, I will get the old selectLayout...How I get the newest selectLayout value which was updated by dispatch action?

https://gist.github.com/sevenLee/7d229a9e5d8e82b1d5e12040f3ae2ee8

```
handleChange(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.props.selectLayoutAction(event.target.value); // update select layout

    this.setState({selectedLayoutOption: event.target.value});

    // I need the newest selectLayout value immediately, but when I only got the old selectLayout value
    // For example: select from layout1 to layout2, I can not get layout2, I got layout1
    this.setState({selectedThemeOption: this.getCurrentTheme(this.props.selectLayout)}); //<--- I can't use this
    this.setState({selectedThemeOption: this.getCurrentTheme(event.target.value)}); //<--- Finally, I replace with  'event.target.value'  for getting the latest value after selectting

    this.props.resetStyles();
 }

render() {
    const { layouts, selectLayout } = this.props;
    let layoutJS = [];

    if (layouts && layouts.toJS) {
      layoutJS = layouts.toJS();
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <select onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} value={this.state.selectedLayoutOption}>
          {this.renderOptions(layoutJS)}
        </select>
      </div>
    );
  }

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  console.log('Update selectLayout!!! ', state.selectLayout);   
  //When I dispatch action, I can get update selectLayout value right away here, but it can't map the state to props right away.
  return {
    layouts: state.layouts,
    selectLayout: state.selectLayout
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({ selectLayoutAction, setLayoutThemeAction, resetStyles }, dispatch);
}
```

Comment: Why do you track the selected item *both* in store and local state? This seems like an anti-pattern to me.

Comment: @lux Do you mean should I put setState in `componentWillReceiveProps`, not position after `selectLayoutAction `?

Comment: @DanAbramov I need to update the component local state for select value and save updated selectLayout to redux....is it anti-pattern? How can I make it to be best practice?

Comment: Why not do all the processing in mapStateToProps. Keep your selected layout in the redux store and project that state out to Props. mapStateToProps will call getCurrentTheme.

Comment: @JoeWood Do you mean I don't need local state anymore, select value is always  from the props mapped by  mapStateToProps? That is why @ DanAbramov said my example is anti-pattern, right?

Comment: It's often better to simplify the component and push the work into the connected container (the map functions). With Redux you can put your entire app state in the redux store and just select the state that your component will use. Changing the active state can be seen as an app state change, so you can set your component property in the mapStateToProps function, alongside any derived data (the themeOption).

Comment: I already fixed my code in the following answer, thank you :)

Comment: @SevenLee did you ever get this working?  I have a similar issue, except I'm using react-redux and reselect... see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57226154/react-redux-reselect-is-mapped-state-to-props-using-selectors-synchronous

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put all states on redux store, don't use local state anymore, use `mapStateToProps` make state as props, then get the latest value from it. It is the best practice I think:

```
  handleChange(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.props.selectLayoutAction(event.target.value);
    this.props.resetStyles();
  }

  handleThemeChange(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.props.setLayoutThemeAction({
      name: this.props.selectLayout,
      currentTheme: event.target.value
    });
  }

  render() {
      const { layouts, selectLayout } = this.props;
      let layoutsList = List(layouts);
      let currentTheme = '';

      if (layouts && layouts.get) {
        let targetLayout = layouts.find((layout) => layout.get('name') === selectLayout);
        currentTheme = targetLayout.get('currentTheme');
      }

      return (
        <div>
          <select onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} value={selectLayout}>
            {this.renderOptions(layoutsList)}
          </select>

          <select onChange={this.handleThemeChange.bind(this)} value={currentTheme}>
            {this.renderThemeOptions(selectLayout, layouts)}
          </select>
        </div>
      );
    }



function mapStateToProps(state) {
  console.log('Update selectLayout!!! ', state.selectLayout);
  syncSelectLayout = state.selectLayout;
  return {
    layouts: state.layouts,
    selectLayout: state.selectLayout
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({ selectLayoutAction, setLayoutThemeAction, resetStyles }, dispatch);
}
```

Comment: But why we use local state, is steel showing the old one ?

Answer (score 4):

That would assume synchronous behavior from redux. Never assume anything about setState and dispatch execution order with redux.
So, what you probably want is to either do full-blown redux and put everything in redux's store, then use mapStateToProps, or use [componentWillReceiveProps](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-componentwillreceiveprops) to trigger your state changes. Putting everything in the redux store and state, that is the preferred long-term option, more maintainable and unit-testable.

Comment: Is `componentWillReceiveProps` deprecated?