# React / Redux / Reselect - is mapped state to props using selectors synchronous or asynchronous?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga, reselect

In our project we are using `react-redux` with `reselect` and `redux-saga`

In the store I have a `selectedStageId` along with an array of `stages` and a memoized selector that finds and returns the correct stage based on the id.

This selector is mapped to one of my components props as `this.props.selectedStage`, and in one of my onClick handlers, I dispatch an action to update the `selectedStageId` to the id of the newly selected UI item, and then attempt to pass the new `selectedStage` to an edit method...

However, even though I have added breakpoints and verified that both my reducers and selectors are being called with the new id, the new `selectedStage` value is NOT being updated synchronously on my component's props... instead `this.props.selectedStage` still references the previous value...

**Example:**

```
onItemSelect = (stageId: number): void => {

  // updateSelectedStageId() is a mapped dispatch method that updates
  // selectedStageId in the store

  this.props.updateSelectedStageId(stageId);

  // I have debugged the above dispatched action and verified that
  // both the reducer and selector are being called with the new
  // stageId, and the selector is executing and returning the correct
  // new stage object before the next line is processed...

  this.editStage(this.props.selectedStage;); // <-- wrong value

  // this.props.selectedStage is the mapped memoized selector that
  // returns the target stage based on the selectedStageId, but
  // here it still references the previous value, not the new one
}
```

I've read that redux is normally synchronous, but that redux-saga could somehow be making this asynchronous... However, since I've verified that both the reducer and selector are being called synchronously, it seems that the issue lies somewhere else, maybe in when connect actually updates mapped state to props...

Can anyone provide some insight on how to accomplish this the right way?

Thanks!

Josh

**UPDATE**

Here are the related bits for my reducer and selector...

*reducer.ts*

```
import produce from 'immer';

const initialState = {
  selectedStageId: -1,
  stages: []
}

export const appReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  return produce(state, (draftState) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case ActionType.UpdateSelectedStageId
        draftState.selectedStageId = action.id;
        break;
    }
  });
}
```

*selectors.ts*

```
import { createSelector } from 'reselect';

const _getSelectedStage = (stages, id) => {
  return stages.find((s) => s.id === id);
};
export const selectedStage = createSelector(
  [getStages, getSelectedStageId],
  _getSelectedStage
);
```

Comment: even if redux is ideally synchronous React still updates component(and provides new props) always in async way.

Comment: is there a way then, similar to `setState` to await or provide a callback so that execution can continue once the new state has been propagated back down to props?

Comment: you can check for `props` changes(regardless their initiator) in `componentDidUpdate` or move related logic in different redux action called subsequently

Comment: It sounds like your reducer might be mutating state. What does your reducer code look like for this action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem (almost the same actually) [today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57222510/unexpected-async-behavior-dispatching-actions).

Every state's change (redux or not) are asynchronous. You can't actually trust the value will be updated.

> Triggering a synchronous action doesn't mean it's synchronous within the current rendering phase. So your app dispatch the action, finishes the rendering, then the new redux state triggers a re-render.

```
dispatch({type: CHANGE_VALUE, value : newValue})
console.log(value) //oldValue
```

The state get's updated synchronously, but React will only be aware of that change in the next render.

So, just use the value you are dispatching the action:

```
onItemSelect = (stageId: number): void => {

  this.props.updateSelectedStageId(stageId);

  this.editStage(stageId)

}
```

Comment: but I'm not concerned about a re-render... I just want access to the new selector value, which IS being set synchronously... is there a way to get this directly?

Comment: The new value will only be available in the next render

Comment: So how then do I work around this? Short of also passing down the array of stages and manually finding the correct one inside my method (which kind of defeats the purpose of the memoized selector I think...)?

Comment: I've updated the answer. Can you use like this? Instead of hoping the `prop` changed in time you could just use `stageId` again.

Comment: I would either A: Do what this answer states and just use `stageId` immediately, or B: if your reducer is doing calculations on your updated values, add code to your lifecycle methods to look for updates to `this.props.selectedStage` and run `this.editStage()` at that time.

Comment: Good point, seems to be the only way. either listen for updates or just use the value immediately

Comment: @DougWatkins I need to run editStage immediately and I need access to the new stage object immediately... according to this, connect / mapStateToProps is supposed to be synchronous... https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapstate

Comment: It is synchronous, react's change detection isn't

Comment: so you're saying that even though every other part of this process chain is synchronous, I still can't access my state updates in the same cycle???  that seems extremely short-sighted to me... it means that I either have to pass down the root state to my component and manually search for the correct stage object (defeating the purpose of memoized selectors), or I have to add some sort of hacky internal state flag like `isEditing` to identify that I should edit the current stage once componentDidUpdate triggers? neither option seems ideal to me...

Comment: I'm saying that React won't cancel a render to start another. At the moment you dispatch the action the state get's updated. But this change will trigger another render, this one have the updated value

Comment: @JoshuaBarker you don't need a flag for that. Just track changes to the values you are interested in. We do this all over our apps. As for memoizing, that only saves you time when things aren't changing, when things are changing you will still need to recompute your values. If the values are so computationally intensive that you don't want to recompute, then compute the value outside of your reducer and pass in the computed value instead. If you need to compute in multiple places, put the computation function in a utility file.

Comment: so, after going round and round I decided to change my approach somewhat... part of why I was trying to send the stage object directly instead of just the id is because of how the state-tree is shaped... the stages array is in a separate reducer / branch from the selectedStageId... Moving forward I'm going to use `reduceReducers` with `combineReducers` to create a shared global reducer that has access to all branches of state... this will allow me to just send the stage id and access the stage from the other state branch...